# Passing of text_field with array value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> > > this code is used to generate 6 empty boxes on thesame row

2,:class => 'xstyle',:id => name %>
                
              




>>> this code is used to pass the value of txtwinentry1 (with 6 values) to controller

  "winningentry",
                         :url => { :action => "checkrow1"  },
                         :with => "'xid1='+$F('winid1')+'&xrange1='+$F('winrange1')+'&xcount1='+ $F('wincount1')
                                             +'&xdesc1='+$F('windesc1')+'&xuser1='+$F('txtuser1')+ '&xwinentry1='+ $F('txtwinentry1')")%>

....given the codes above, no values passed from &xwinentry1='+ $F('txtwinentry1') to the controller.

Any information or suggestion to help me solve the problem will be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit complicated to understand and I think there are better ways to do what you're trying to (for example, using the form.serialize that is default to the rails remote_form_for: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M002178).

Any way, I could notice that when you're generating the 6 text boxes, you concatenate "txtwinetry1" with the counter, witch gives you something like "txtwinetry11", "txtwinetry12", ... That means that your supposed to do something like '&xwinentry1='+ $F('txtwinentry11')") in your button_to_remote function.

Comment: hi..thanks for the quick response. Actually i've already tried to use form.serialize. I was able to display the output in a message box just to check if text_field txtwinentry1 contains values, and it have. My problem was, i cannot passed those values from view to controller. I do not know how to pass the values generated in java script to button_to_remote function. 
Anyway thank you very for the help. I've done it using orm_remote_tag